# Python: Read next line in a file in one simple line of code

Tags: python, iterator, readline

As the title says, I would like to use a simple command to make Python read the next line of a text file.
For example something like this:

```
users = open("C:\\Users\\Tharix\\Desktop\\test.txt",mode="r")
line = test.readline(20)
print(line)
line.next() #Or something similar
print(line)
```

(PS: I don't know this helps, but I'm using version 3.3.2 of Python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply iterate over the file object:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Tharix\\Desktop\\test.txt", mode="r") as users:
    for line in users:
       print(line)
```

Note that `iter.next()` has been renamed to `iter.__next__()` in py3.x, or better use `next(iter)`.(This works in both py2.7, py3.x)

Comment: And one more thing, is that if you are going to try calling `FooIterator.__next__()` yourself, you actually need to write it as `FooIterator._FooIterator_next__()`, because of the way the name mangling invoked by the `__` prefix works.

Comment: @hcwhsa  
That's not what I exactly meant,
Edit:
Nevermind, got it

Comment: `a = iter("hello"); a.__next__()` works for me. Name mangling is only when the attribute starts with `__` and doesn't end with it.

Comment: @user2802035 Use `line = next(users)` (which is what hcwhsa said).